# How can I list all installed packages along with their APT origin hostnames (not their origin tags)?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg, aptitude

I'm trying to limit the risk in using third-party APT repositories. The scenario I'm trying to protect against is a malicious package being introduced into a third-party repo with a newer version than the version I have installed from Debian.

Lately whenever I've added a new APT source, I've used APT pinning to make only certain packages installable from that source, like so:

```
Package: *
Pin: origin debian.nabijaczleweli.xyz
Pin-Priority: -1

Package: systemd-zram
Pin: origin debian.nabijaczleweli.xyz
Pin-Priority: 500
```

Note that I am using `Pin: origin <hostname>` rather than `Origin: <tag>` to do this. If I understand correctly, the origin tag is controlled by the repo itself (in the Releases file) and can easily be set to `debian`, either maliciously or because of ignorance. (I have seen this in the wild.) By contrast, the origin hostname is derived from the URI specified in `sources.list`.

This seems to work just fine, and now I want to apply this to all my third-party APT sources. To do this, I need to know which packages I've installed from each third-party repository. The problem is, I can't seem to find a way to get a list of installed packages and their origin URIs or hostnames.

Aptitude is happy to show you `Origin URI` on its [package information screen](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s02s02.en.html#secPackageInfo)¹, but does not include a [search predicate](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html) for it nor will it display it in [package lists](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s05s01.en.html#secDisplayFormat).

`dpkg-query` and `apt-cache` can give me a lot of information about packages, but I haven't yet found a way to get the origin URI or hostname.

I assume I could parse the contents of `/var/lib/apt/lists/*_Packages` myself, using the first part of the filename as the origin hostname, but I'd prefer not to subject myself to that.

So:

1. Is this scenario even worth considering? Maybe there are so many ways that a compromised repo can screw me over that I should learn to stop worrying and love the bomb.
2. Am I correct that the `Releases` file's `Origin` field is less reliable an indication of a package's provenance than the origin hostname used in `Pin: origin <hostname>`?
3. Is there a way to get a list of all installed packages along with their origin hostnames?

Thanks!

¹The screenshot on that page is too old to depict the `Origin-URI` field being shown, but modern versions of Aptitude show the complete URI of the package here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems `aptitude` is dumb... for the logic you want.

A workaround is to resort to Python:

```py
import apt

CACHE = apt.Cache()

for pkg in CACHE:
    if not pkg.installed:
        continue
    for orig in pkg.candidate.origins if pkg.candidate else []:
        if len(orig.site) == 0:
            continue
        print(pkg, pkg.candidate.version, orig.site)
```

**UPDATE** The package `apt` comes with:

```
bash# dpkg -S /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py
python3-apt: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py
```

Comment: The apt package is not part of Python3's "batteries included".

Neither did I find something which looks to be relevant in pypi.
The nearest one I found was apt-wrapper but its documentation does not include this use case.

Can you please add also instructions how to find the apt package to be imported?

Comment: @OmerZak one year later you probably already found this but for those who'd stumble by the apt module referred to by gavenkoa can be made available by installing the python3-apt Debian package.